# How to set up QUERY with different actions based on result value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help on how to set up an QUERY that will result in different outputs based on the results that it achieves on the way and I'm completely stuck!

I'll give you some more details, first of all, here's my current database setup:

```
#USERS
id   username etc.. 
1    alex123
2    bonnie9
3    clyde_x

#COURSES
id   course_name   visibility etc..
1    Name 1        1
2    Name 2        0
3    Name 3        1

#COURSE_ENROLMENT
id   user_id   course_id
1    1         1
2    1         2
3    3         1
```

The scenario is as following..

I need to list the courses to the users that are enrolled to it, which is quite easily done by something like:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM COURSES C
JOIN COURSE_ENROLMENT E ON C.ID = E.COURSE_ID
```

However. If the course visibility (Database: Course, Column: visibility) is set to be visible for everyone = 1, then it will override or just ignore the enrolment and show the course to all users anyway.

How can I achieve something like this? I've tried to research CASE but can't really figure out how to proceed. Greatest thanks for any help!

Comment: Better post your expected results.

Comment: Is this a homework question? I'm sure I've seen this before..

Comment: @forpas I'll add the expected results, give me a minute.

Comment: @JimJimson It's not a homework question, I tried to search for simular problems but didn't find any good examples.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this you're going to need to LEFT JOIN your COURSE and COURSE_ENROLLMENT tables using an OR, so either the person is enrolled in the subject OR the visibility is set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`, that will give you all courses, regardless of whether someone has enrolled in them or not. You can then filter out the courses which have not had anyone enrolled and are not visible by checking for `visibility = 1`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Courses C
LEFT JOIN Course_Enrolment E ON C.id = E.course_id
WHERE C.visibility = 1 OR E.id IS NOT NULL
```

Output:

```
id  course_name visibility  id      user_id course_id
1   Name 1      1           1       1       1
2   Name 2      0           2       1       2
1   Name 1      1           3       3       1
3   Name 3      1           null    null    null
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/txvzHbV7YCz1qsh7wGeSS4/0)

Answer (score 0):

If `visibility=1` means that the course will be returned for all users, then you can do it with a cross join for that case and UNION ALL:

```
select c.course_name, u.username
from users u 
inner join course_enrolment e on e.user_id = u.id 
inner join (
  select * from courses where visibility = 0  
) c on c.id = e.course_id
union all
select c.course_name, u.username
from users u 
cross join (
  select * from courses where visibility = 1  
) c 
order by course_name, username
```